# Are there any set of rules on when induction can or cannot be applied?

Tags: induction, axioms

I know this is some sort of "common-sense" question, but I want to get a clear boundary on this: when can I apply / cannot apply induction on a proof?

For example, I know that:

> Ex1) A person with 1 hair is bald.
>
> If a person has n hair and is bald, he is bald even when he has n+1 hair.

is a wrong application of induction.

Similarly, induction doesn't work on big-Os.

SO my question is, are there any "axiomatic idea" or anything that defines the boundary on when induction can be applied?

Thanks : )

Comment: Induction works if the notions you are working with are well-defined? Can you elaborate what induction on big-Os doesn't work. I'm interested in that. : - )

Comment: @K.Stm. see MIT's introduction to algorithms lecture, and in lecture 1~3 (forgot which part), the lecturer shows that it's 'possible' to do induction on big-O to prove O(n) = O(n^2), but shouldn't. (I'll explain about this later - gotta go)

Answer (score 1):

Induction works for all formal predicates on natural numbers.

It's ok that induction fails for the predicate bald(n) (where n is the number of hairs a person has) because notions like this are not formal, they are just rough classifications (not really the realm of mathematics).